# Grails: Unit test domain class constraint gives wrong result

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, grails-2.0

I'm trying to write unit tests for my domain class to test constraints but I got unexpected result. Here is my domain class:

```
class Student {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank:false,minSize:2,maxSize:20,validator: { val, obj ->
                      def similarUser = Student.findByFirstNameIlikeAndLastNameIlike(obj.firstName, obj.lastName)
                      if(!similarUser || obj.id == similarUser.id){
                      return ['Student.invalid.unique.message']
                      }
                    }
        lastName blank:false, minSize:2,maxSize:20
    }

}
```

and here is my unit tests:

```
@TestFor(Student)
@Mock(Student)
class StudentTests {
    def st

    @Before
    void setUp(){       
        mockForConstraintsTests(Student)        
        st=new Student(firstName:"FerasO",lastName:"Ahmad")     

    }


    @Test
    void testMinSize() {                
        assertTrue student.validate() // I guess this should return true but It returns false

    }

}
```

What is going wrong with that? How could I solve it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something wrong this code:

```
if(!similarUser || obj.id == similarUser.id)
```

should be  `if(similarUser && obj.id == similarUser.id)`